# Changing order of a phrase

Tags: grammar, phrase

So I watched a movie.  I thought would be fun to see if I could re-order the phrase.

Phrase 1 original:  不能说的就不要说.  To: 就不要说不能说的.

Phrase 2 original: 阻止他说不该说的话. To:  不该说的话阻止他说.

Are the two re-order correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phrase 1 original: 不能说的就不要说. To: 就不要说不能说的.

Phrase 2 original: 阻止他说不该说的话. To: 不该说的话阻止他说.

These two phrases are ok.

> The first one is a little strange because 就 can't be used in the
> beginning of the sentence in this way. Get rid of 就 and it's fine.

就 can use at the beginning of a sentence without any problem.

e.g.

Q: 午餐想吃甚麼？
A: 就幫我買個便當好了。

Q: 為什麼這電腦老是有問題？
A: 就跟你說不要安裝來路不明的軟體。

Q: 為什麼你洗衣服用溫水洗？
A: 就我的經驗來看，溫水洗得比較乾淨。

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a fun practice!

The first one is a little strange because 就 can't be used in the beginning of the sentence in this way. Get rid of 就 and it's fine.

The second one is correct (with a different emphasis).

Answer (score 1):

> Phrase 1 original: 不能说的就不要说. To: 就不要说不能说的.

It almost works, 就 in the 2nd phrase should be omitted. **不要说不能说的**
But in oral language, some people like to use 就 before their statement, in this case, 就 is for softening your voice, don't have any grammar functions.
So it almost works.

> Phrase 2 original: 阻止他说不该说的话. To: 不该说的话阻止他说.

It sounds odd and ambiguous. It could be interpreted as:

1 What shouldn't be said, stop him to say.

2 If it shouldn't be said, stop him to say.

XXX的话 can do a subjunctive mood, so it is ambiguous.